Can't run wicket maven command from homepage
I'm trying to build a wicket project on a mac using the generated command from the wicket homepage:
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=9.18.0 -DgroupId=com.rdfined -DartifactId=wicket -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/ -DinteractiveMode=false

I get an error though I don't understand:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.3.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error merging velocity templates: Encountered "#end" at archetype-resources/pom.xml[line 204, column 9]
[ERROR] Was expecting one of:

Does anyone know what this is about?

This is a known issue which has been already solved but not been published yet.
As a workaround you can use the snapshot version for the moment:
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=10.3.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ -DinteractiveMode=false

